# How to Get SelectOneRadio Value in Oracle ADF withour Value Change listener

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-adf, selectoneradio

I want to get the selected value in the SelectOneRadio in Oracle ADF jsff.

The problem is that i dont want to refer each and every click to a ValueChangeListener.

That creates a lot of server load.

is there any way to get the value selected in the radio button and display it in an output text by partially updating it and all..

I have tried multiple Blogs all referring to use of BackingBean.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a binding to that component, and get it's value within the same method where the bind is. For example:

```
<af:selectOneRadio value="#{bindings.Deptno.inputValue}" label="Select Department"
                        required="true" shortDesc="#{bindings.Deptno.hints.tooltip}"
                        id="soc1" autoSubmit="true" binding="#{managedBeanName.selectOneRadio}>
      <f:selectItems value="#{bindings.Deptno.items}" id="si1"/>
```

and then the bean should look like this:

```
import oracle.adf.view.rich.component.rich.input.RichSelectOneRadio

public class ManagedBeanName{
private RichSelectOneRadio radio;

//getters/setters for 'radio' here

public void printValue(){
System.out.println(radio.getValue());
}
```

The last thing would be the call to this method each time *YOU* want to print/get the selected value.

Answer (score 0):

A call to a `ValueChangeListener` should not overload the server.

Try

```
<af:selectOneRadio value="#{bean.aValue}" id="sor1" autoSubmit="true">
  <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option1" itemValue="1"/>
  <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option2" itemValue="2"/>
  <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option3" itemValue="3"/>
</af:selectOneRadio>
<af:outputText value="#{bean.aValue}" partialTriggers="sor1"/>
```

No `ValueChangeListener` but still a trip on the server. You can't avoid that. ADF is based on JSF and this is the way the technology works.